# WPF Blur text in textbox

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml

I want to set blur text in Textbox and PasswordBox.
When Textbox and PasswordBox is focused, that blur text will disappear and when lost focus, blur text will reappear.
Any solution?

Answer (score 3):

You can use triggers to dynamically change value of a property under certain conditions. In this case you can set `Effect` property value to `BlurEffect` when the control is focused like this:

```
<Style x:Key="BlurEffect" TargetType="{x:Type Control}">
    <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="IsFocused" Value="False">
            <Setter Property="Effect">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <BlurEffect Radius="5"></BlurEffect>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

Then you apply your style to you control:

```
<TextBox Style="{StaticResource BlurEffect}" />
<PasswordBox Style="{StaticResource BlurEffect}" />
```

You can apply this style to any element derived from `Control` class.